# Data matrix scan works very slow and imprecise with ZBar on Android

Tags: android, image-processing, zbar-sdk, zbar, datamatrix

I integrated zBar library in my Android project in order to scan multiple types of codes, including data matrix. The library works very fast and precise for QR code and bar code, but when it comes to data matrix, I hardly get any result. In most of the cases it doesn't recognize it at all. I could get some results, but after many tries and many seconds of scanning. I've noticed some apps on Google Play that claim to use Zbar and they work good for Data Matrix.
Is there anything I could change or fix in the library in order to increase the precision for DataMatrix? Or is there an alternative for Zbar that can works better for this particular case? Thank you!

Comment: Did you end up finding an answer to this? Also what is the code for data matrix?

Comment: Did you manage to sort this?  What did you do to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try less value for Config.X_DENSITY and Config.Y_DENSITY.